# QLineEdit bug in access to its text

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

please guide me in finding the problem of this simplified code in reading text from qlineedit. My code exit in editUser->text() line. Every thing else is ok when I remove this line.

```
#include ...
QString USERID_LOG="SomeThing";
logDialog::logDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::logDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QLineEdit* editUser= new QLineEdit( this );
    QPushButton* okButton = new QPushButton(tr("OK"));
    connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(okSlot()));
     ...
}
void logDialog::okSlot()
{  USERID_LOG=editUser->text();  //////// Error is here
   logDialog::accept();
   return; }

QString logDialog::GetUser()
{
return(USERID_LOG);
}
////////////////////////////logdialog.h/////////////////////////
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class logDialog; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class logDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
    logDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~logDialog();
     QString GetUser();
 public slots:
    void okSlot();
private:
    QLineEdit* editUser;
    QPushButton* okButton;
    Ui::logDialog *ui;
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The `editUser` you initialize in the constructor is local to the constructot -- it's *not* the class member of the same name.  Hence the class member `editUser` is left uninitialized resulting in undefined behaviour.  Similarly for `okButton`.

Comment: @ Retired Ninja, it is : The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: @G.M. , Thank you very much.  I remove QLineEdit* and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your constructor...

```
logDialog::logDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::logDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QLineEdit* editUser= new QLineEdit( this );
    QPushButton* okButton = new QPushButton(tr("OK"));
    connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(okSlot()));
     ...
}
```

The lines...

```
QLineEdit* editUser= new QLineEdit( this );
QPushButton* okButton = new QPushButton(tr("OK"));
```

redeclare/redefine two locally scoped variables `editUser` and `okButton` that shadow the member variables of the same names.  Instead you should simply initialize the member variables themselves...

```
editUser= new QLineEdit( this );
okButton = new QPushButton(tr("OK"));
```

Or, perhaps better, perform the initialization in the ctor's initializer list...

```
logDialog::logDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , editUser(new QLineEdit(this))
    , okButton(new QPushButton(tr("OK")))
    , ui(new Ui::logDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(okSlot()));
    ...
```